# Use ProgressDialog in an AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm develop my first Android Application. I tried every snipped of code i found in this page and others. Well, my problem is a need log in an user using an Internet Service, so i use  an AsyncTask class, but when i tried to add an ProgressDialog into the background method, this dialog show only a second later that the background method finished. It seems like the UI is blocked while the background process is running.

This is the code of my activity and the async class.

```
public class PanelAdministracion extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.paneladministracion);
    try {
        Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        Map<String,String> credenciales = new HashMap<String,String>();
        credenciales.put("usuario", datos.getString("usuario"));
        credenciales.put("password", datos.getString("password"));
        new ObtenerDatos().execute(credenciales,null,null).get();
        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class ObtenerDatos extends AsyncTask< Map<String,String>, Void, Void>{

    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private final static String TAG = "LoginActivity.EfetuaLogin";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v(TAG, "Executando onPreExecute de EfetuaLogin");
        //inicia diálogo de progresso, mostranto processamento com servidor.
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PanelAdministracion.this, "Autenticando", "Contactando o servidor, por favor, aguarde alguns instantes.", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Map<String,String>... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Executando doInBackground de EfetuaLogin");
        try {
            if(Usuario.login(params[0].get("usuario"), params[0].get("password"))){
                Usuario.obtenerNotificaciones();
                Usuario.obtenerPeliculas();
                Usuario.obtenerSeries();
            }else{
                Intent volver = new Intent(PanelAdministracion.this,SerieslyActivity.class);
                PanelAdministracion.this.startActivity(volver);
            }
        } catch (NotSignInException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GetDataSerieException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Thank you everyone of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root point that makes your UI thread block is:

```
new ObtenerDatos().execute(credenciales,null,null).get();
```

By calling AsyncTask.get(), you are actually making you UI thread block and wait for worker thread (AKA. AsyncTask.doInBackground()) to finish. in another word, by doing that, your AsyncTask is running synchronously with UI thread. Try using:

```
new ObtenerDatos().execute(credenciales,null,null);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

--> protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;

Write this line at class level..

Comment: What does mean? I should write that without protected atribute?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this...

```
public class PanelAdministracion extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.paneladministracion);
    try {
        Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        Map<String,String> credenciales = new HashMap<String,String>();
        credenciales.put("usuario", datos.getString("usuario"));
        credenciales.put("password", datos.getString("password"));

        // Keep progressDialog outside of AsyncTask...
        // This all could be put in a separate method to clean things up...
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PanelAdministracion.this, "Autenticando", "Contactando o servidor, por favor, aguarde alguns instantes.", true, false);

        new AsyncTask<Map<String,String>, Void, Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Map<String,String>... params) {
                // Your other code goes here...
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }.execute(credenciales);


        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);

        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```